# erro no require_once include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR'

Tags: php, html

O que é esse erro:

> Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs...\CRUD.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs...\CRUD.php on line 2

Obs.: O arquivo **config.php** existe, e esta em uma pasta anterior a que esta sendo chamado o `require`.

Comment: Pode mandar o trecho do código em questão? Isso me parece um erro de sintaxe

Comment: <?
php require_once '../config.php';
?>

Depois é o restante do código. Mais essa é a linha de erro

Comment: Utilize o caminho absoluto ao invés de "../". `require_once __DIR__."/config.php"`, por exemplo.

Comment: A constante __DIR__ não funcionou porque o arquivo config,php esta em uma pasta anterior. E como o "../" não esta funcionando para voltar uma pasta, acabou não dando certo.
Então coloquei o caminho completo "C:/xampp/htdocs/.../config.php e funcionou.
Mais se tiver uma forma melhor que esta que eu fiz, agradeço.

Comment: Vi esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows se é que ajuda. Tou é cpm dúvidas como é que se faz para include_path=C:\xampp\php\PEAR... Se alguém puder ajudar. Estou com o mesmo problema